# Windows task processor twice per day

Tags: windows, triggers, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible configure to run Windows task (from the Task Scheduler) every day two times per day (in the morning and in the evening) ?

Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 1):

Yep. You should be able to create two daily triggers with different start times.

Make sure that you're not creating a basic task, but choose **Create a task**

Click on the triggers tab and and however many triggers you fancy :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer